# Titanium JS: Error using Alloy data binding: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '__alloyId60.on')

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I've created a new controller (`search.js`) in Titanium Alloy, within which I have referenced one of my collections:

**`search.js`**

```
var searchResults = Alloy.Collections.searchResults;
```

And then in my view (`search.xml`) I've created a TableView, and added the dataCollection attribute:

**`search.xml`**

```
<TableView id="resultsTable" dataCollection="searchResults">
    <TableViewRow title="{name}" />
</TableView>
```

In my controller, this collection gets populated with data via an online API, when the user does a search. In this code, `results` is a JSON object containing all the data:

**`search.js`**

```
_.each(results, function (item) {
   var beer = Alloy.createModel('searchResults', item);
   searchResults.push(beer);
});
```

When I run my app, I get the following error message:

> "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '__alloyId60.on')"

I don't see where I am going wrong, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this error by defining the global instance of my collection in my `alloy.js` file:

```
Alloy.Collections.searchResults = Alloy.createCollection('searchResults');
```

I found it from **[this answer](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148555/alloy-models---undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-alloycollectionsmodelnameon-at-indexjs-line-46)** on the Appcelerator developer forums.